# get most counted word or phrase on webpage -> store in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

If the below code goes through my webpage text and counts all instances of words and outputs in the dev console. How could I add a sort function that sorts this to display words with highest number of instances or integer counted, and then stores said highest counted word in a variable that I could use later?

```
var words = [];

var walkDOM = function (node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while(node) {
        walkDOM(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }

};

walkDOM(document.body, function (node) {

    if (node.nodeName === '#text') {
        var text = node.textContent;

        text = text.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, ' ');

        text = text.split(' ');

        if (text.length) {

            for (var i = 0, length = text.length; i < length; i += 1) {
                var matched = false,
                    word = text[i];

                for (var j = 0, numberOfWords = words.length; j < numberOfWords; j += 1) {
                    if (words[j][0] === word) {
                        matched = true;
                        words[j][1] += 1;
                    }
                }

                if (!matched) {
                    words.push([word, 1]);
                }

            }
        }
    }
});

var displayWordList = function (words) {
    for (var i = 0, length = words.length; i < length; i += 1) {
        console.log(words[i][0], words[i][1]);
    }
};

displayWordList(words);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an if statement to your code to exclude blank words.

https://jsfiddle.net/Delorian/qcp1ujum/

```
words.sort(function(a, b) { return b[1] - a[1]; });
var result = '';
words.forEach(function (word) { result += '<br />' + word[0] + ' - ' + word[1]; });

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;

const mostOccurring = words[0][0];

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = document.getElementById('result').innerHTML + '<br /><br />var mostOccurring is: ' + mostOccurring;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use JavaScript's built in `sort` method:

```
words.sort(function(a, b){
    return a[1] < b[1];
})
```

That will sort the words (descending) array using the second value in the sub-arrays. To do ascending, reverse the comparison statement in the `return`.